# US Senate Floor Leaders: What happens if there is a substantial third party?

Tags: united-states, senate

According to the [US Senate's web site](https://www.senate.gov/reference/reference_index_subjects/Leadership_vrd.htm),

> Leadership
> The floor leaders and whips of each party are elected by a majority vote of all the senators of their party assembled in a conference or, as it sometimes is called, a caucus. The practice has been to choose the leader for a two-year term at the beginning of each Congress. The majority and minority leaders are the elected spokespersons on the Senate floor for their respective political parties.

and

> floor leaders - The majority leader and minority leader are elected by their respective party conferences to serve as the chief Senate spokesmen for their parties and to manage and schedule the legislative and executive business of the Senate. By custom, the presiding officer gives the floor leaders priority in obtaining recognition to speak on the floor of the Senate.

This seems to indicate there are one Majority Leader and one Minority Leader. Right now, they are chosen by the Democrats and Republicans, respectively. While there are two Independents, they caucus with the Democrats. There seems to be a more than a trivial possibility that the Republican party might split in the coming months. We don't know what the split off party would be called, I'll refer to them as the Trumpists. If that happens, there would be more than a small group, and one might envision them not wishing to caucus with the "true" Republicans. If that occurred, the Democrats would definitely be the Majority, but who would be the Minority Leader?

(Note: I don't want to start a dialog about which group would be the "true" Republicans, that is not my purpose here.)